# Are these subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

The spaces are $\mathbb{R} \times [0,1]$ and $\mathbb{R} \times (-\infty,0]$.

So, if [0,1] was either [0,1) or (0,1] showing homeomorphism is trivial. However, the inclusion of both the points leads me to believe that there will not even exist a (surjective) continuous map between the two spaces.

Comment: There are plenty of continuous maps (just as there are plenty of continuous maps from $[0,1]$ to $(-\infty,0]$, and plenty in the other direction). Continuous, bijective maps, on the other hand, are more difficult to find.

Comment: @Arthur No. If there was then the image of $[0,1]$ would be bounded while the other set is not.

Comment: However, even that observation will not really help us with a formal proof for this!!

Comment: It sounds like you're restricting attention to *surjections*. There are plenty of continuous maps from $\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}\times (-\infty, 0]$, such as $$(a,b)\mapsto (a,b-17).$$

Comment: $x\mapsto x-1$ is a continuous map from $[0,1]$ to $(-\infty,0]$. And $x\mapsto -\frac{1}{x-1}$ is a continuous map from $(-\infty,0]$ to $[0,1]$. And there are many more where those came from.

Comment: @Arthur Haha! Let's keep the maps surjective. xP

Comment: @Adienl Sure. But then you ought to say so from the get-go. Your question post says "there will not even exist a continuous map between the two spaces." That's false, and it was what I was responding to.

Comment: @Arthur. Sorry! I will edit that right away.

Comment: I think you can show that these spaces are not homeomorphic by using [ends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology)). The first space has two ends but the second has only one end. You can see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221979/proving-that-s1-times-mathbbr2-is-not-homeomorphic-to-s2-times-mathbb/3222185#3222185) where I use ends as an example.

Comment: @AdamChalumeau Seems pretty interesting. I shall have a look!

Answer (score 5):

No. The only proof I can come up with uses some algebraic topology:

Both $\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{R}\times(-\infty,0]$ are topological manifolds with boundaries. The boundary of $\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]$ consists of two lines, and is disconnected. The boundary of $\mathbb{R}\times(-\infty,0]$ is a line, and connected.

However, any homeomorphism between topological manifolds with boundaries restricts to a homeomorphism between their boundaries; see

- [Do homeomorphic manifolds with boundary have homeomorphic interiors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3304836/do-homeomorphic-manifolds-with-boundary-have-homeomorphic-interiors/3307422#3307422),

(the boundary of a manifold is the complement of its interior) so those spaces are not homeomorphic.

Comment: I don't know algebraic topology. I suppose I should start reading up on it. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I guess you don't in fact need all that much algebraic topology to apply your argument; just knowing that the circle is not contractible is enough. For both these spaces, you can tell whether a point is a boundary point or not according to whether its removal leaves you with a contractible space or space that is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$.

Answer (score 3):

I think Luiz's answer is right on the money, but here is an alternative anyway. If these spaces were homeomorphic, then so would be their 1-point compactifications. However, the 1-point compactification of $\mathbb{R} \times [0,1]$ is homotopy equivalent to the circle $S^1$, whereas the 1-point compactification of $\mathbb{R} \times (-\infty,0]$ is contractible (it is homeomorphic to the closed 2-disk). So, as long as you have enough tools to know that the circle is not contractible, you can apply these observations to conclude that the spaces are not homeomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that doesn't use any algebraic topology; you only need Heine-Borel. If you remove a compact subset from $\mathbb{R} \times (-\infty,0]$ the remainder has only one (connected) component whose closure is not compact. If you do the same to $\mathbb{R} \times [0,1]$ the remainder can have two such components.

Comment: This does not work; homeomorphisms between open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ do not necessarily extend to their closures. Alternatively, change $\mathbb{R}\times(-\infty,0]$ and $\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]$ by the homeomorphic sets $(0,1)\times(0,1]$ and $(0,1)\times[0,1]$, so the argument does not work anymore (all closures of their subsets are compact).

Comment: But homoemorphisms between whole spaces do respect the closures of their subsets. A homoemorphism between $X$ and $Y$ will take components of $X\setminus K$ to components of $Y \setminus f(K)$ and their closures (in $X$) to the closures of the components in $Y$. A component with compact closure in $X$ will correspond to one with the same property in $Y$. (Essentially my answer is just an attempt at a proof that the one space has two ends and the other only one, without bothering to define ends. I see now that Adam Chalumeau had already suggested using ends in a comment.)